# AngularJs toggle ng-class ng-click

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone offer the correct approach to this JSFiddle:

```
<style>
 .red #btn{
     background-color:red;
  }

 .blue #btn{
    background-color:blue;
  }
 </style>

 <body ng-app="ap" ng-controller="con">
    <button id="btn" ng-click="changeClass()">Change Class</button>    
 </body>

 <script>
  var app = angular.module("ap",[]);

  app.controller("con",function($scope){

  $scope.class = "red";

  $scope.changeClass = function(){
     if ($scope.class === "red #btn")
         $scope.class = "blue #btn";
      else
         $scope.class = "red #btn";
   };
 });

 </script>
```

**[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/baa2G/2/)**

I am trying to change the class of an element via .class & #ID.

Thanks in advance

**Thanks tymeJV, new JSFiddle:**

[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/baa2G/2/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The correct approach would be using `ng-class` based on a toggle variable, consider:

CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$scope.toggle = false;
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">Change Class</button>
```

`ng-class` works by assigning the referenced class (in the above, "red") based on if the variable ("toggle") is `true` or `false`.

Comment: tymeJV: Question. What if I have a <div id="SomeDiv"></div> and I want to change it's color with the button click?

Comment: Put the `ng-class` on that element

Comment: tymeJV: I know I am pushing my luck here, hehe, but how to toggle between red and blue?

Comment: Ahh not sure of the syntax off the top of my head, but you can do it with `ng-cass` - try searching for `ng-class if else`

Comment: @tymeJV Have someone told you before ? You're genius :) Worked like a charm !!

Comment: EPIC - the secret to awsome angular dom manipulation laid out bare

Comment: Question: I'm using this technique in an ng-repeat to create an accordion effect. Each element in the accordion has its own ng-click with toggle = !toggle. This works great, except now I need to display only one open element at a time? Is there a way to have each click set all other "toggles" to false before toggling the clicked element?

Comment: @user1486941 - Since `ngRepeat` creates its own scope, the above method probably wont work - you'll need to add a property to each element in the array and set all of the false each click, then set the clicked to `true` to only get one at a time (at least this is one way)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I ended up just creating two simple functions in the controller, setSelected(obj) and isSelected(obj). ngClick calls setSelected(obj) which contains a call to isSelected(obj) to determine how to set $scope.selected (boolean). isSelected(obj) compares $scope.selected to the calling object, and assigns the class 'active' when true. Thanks for the inspiration!