# Toggle class with ng-click on several elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

How can I toggle classes on several elements individually with ng-click?

In this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/22072110/2169327 toggling classes with a click was done like this:

CSS:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$scope.toggle = false;
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">Change Class</button>
```

But what if I have several buttons that each should toggle its own class with ng-click?

If I set it up in this way:

HTML:

```
<button id="btn" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">Change Class</button>
<button id="btn2" ng-click="toggle = !toggle" ng-class="{'red' : toggle}">Change Class</button>
```

Both buttons get toggled if I press one.

I know a workaround is to define an own ng-click event for each button (f.ex toggle1 for button1, toggle2 for button2) - but is this the best way?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I made simple directive for testing:

```
module.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

so you can make any element toggle class you need

```
<button id="btn" toggle-class="active">Change Class</button>
<div toggle-class="whatever"></div>
```

Comment: How do you declare the two classes that will be toggled? i.e say you have a div: <div class="class_one">random content here</div>, and you want to toggle "class_one" to "class_two"? All of the examples I've seen for this just have active as the class being toggled.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland in your case I think you want to use `toggleClass` twice, once for "class_one" and once for "class_two". All `toggleClass` does is check to see if the class is already there and act accordingly: if it is there, it removes it, and if it isn't there, it adds it.

Comment: @zombi how can I toggle a class of an elements say "B", by clicking element "A"?

Comment: You can do it for example like this:

`.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                if (attrs.toggleClassOn) {
                    var e = document.querySelectorAll(attrs.toggleClassOn);
                    angular.element(e).toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
                } else {
                    element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
                }
            });
        }
    };
})`

Answer (score 18):

Depending on your requirements, you may be able to use an `ng-repeat` with an array representing the toggles. For example:

Your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="toggle in toggles">
    <button id="btn" ng-click="toggle.state = !toggle.state" ng-class="{'red' : toggle.state}">Change Class</button>
</div>
```

Inside your controller:

```
$scope.toggles = [{ state: true }, { state: false }, { state: true }];
```

This way you can expand on your button set by simply updating the array, or the internal array objects (should you need more complexity).

Answer (score 1):

inside controller

```
 $scope.stateToggle=false;
$scope.togglelasses=function(){
     $scope.stateToggle= !$scope.stateToggle;
}
```

in view use ng-class

```
 <button ng-click="togglelasses()" ng-class="stateToggle? 'active ': ' '">
```

add ng-class in every element where you want  class active