# How to make only one menu item active at a time using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make only one menu item as active.But when I click on specific menu item I'm getting all the menu items active.

I want to remove the previous active menu item and make the current clicked menu item as active.Can anyone please help me out regarding this.

My js:

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

       $scope.isActive = true;
        $scope.highlight = function () {


            if (!$(event.target).hasClass("active")) {
                $(event.target).addClass("active");
                $(event.target).children().addClass("glyphicon-triangle-top");
            } else {
                $(event.target).removeClass('active');
                $(event.target).children().removeClass("glyphicon-triangle-top");
            }
        }


    });
```

My html:

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li id="li-home">
                            <a ng-click="highlight()" class="active" href="#/">Home
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top active-elem"></span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="li-about"><a ng-click="highlight()" ng-href="#/about">About
                    <span class="glyphicon active-elem"></span>
                  </a></li>
                        <li id="li-contact"><a ng-click="highlight()" ng-href="#/">Contact
                    <span class="glyphicon active-elem"></span>
                  </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So...I'll give you another approach to doing this as your code seems like the hard way of doing things. The key-difference is that I'm using **[ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)** to dynamically set the class of the active tab:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

   $scope.isActive = 'home';
   $scope.highlight = function(tab) {
     $scope.isActive = tab;
   }
});
```

html:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="li-home" ng-class="{activeTab: isActive === 'home'">
      <a ng-click="highlight('active')"  href="#/">
        Home
        <span ng-show="isActive === 'home'" class="glyphicon active-elem</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-about" ng-class="{activeTab: isActive === 'about'">
      <a ng-click="highlight('about)" ng-href="#/about">
        About
        <span ng-show="isActive === 'about'" class="glyphicon active-elem"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="li-contact" ng-class="{activeTab: isActive === 'contact'">
      <a ng-click="highlight('contact)" ng-href="#/">
        Contact
        <span ng-show="isActive === 'contact'" class="glyphicon active-elem"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.activeTab {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Here I want to remove the glyphicon when that particualr menu item is not active

Comment: oh...then you can use *ng-show* on the element with the glyphicon to only show it when that item is active. I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Ok just updated my answer. By using ng-show you can control when the glyphicon element is going to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple directive which will toggle the active class on the element.

Please refer..

[Toggle class with ng-click on several elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141139/toggle-class-with-ng-click-on-several-elements)