# jQuery toggle class | one of many at a time - the Angular way (not ngRepeat)

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I wrote a little method to toggle a CSS class on one of a group. It allows only one element to have that class at a time. These elements are not a list and don't necessarily have a common parent. The only thing grouping them is a common CSS class.

I'm working with an Angular 1.5 project and trying to let Angular do the work it's way. Is there a preferred way to deal with this for Angular lovers? All of the doc examples either work with one element or with ngRepeat and $index.

Here is an example of how this is differen't than jQuery's toggleClass() on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/pyEWxW)

Thanks. : )

Markup

```
<div class='thing'>one</div>
<div class='thing'>two</div>
<div class='thing'>three</div>
<div class='thing'>four</div>
<div class='thing'>five</div>
```

Style

```
.active
    color: red
```

jQuery plug-in

```
$.fn.toggleBetween = function(className) {
    var $element = this;
    $element.on('click', function() {
        var $target = $(this);
        var currentlyActive = $target.hasClass(className);
        if ( currentlyActive ) {
            $target.removeClass(className);
        } else {
            $element.removeClass(className);
            $target.addClass(className);
        }
    });
    return this;
};

$('.thing').toggleBetween('active');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle class with ng-click on several elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25141139/toggle-class-with-ng-click-on-several-elements)

Comment: @RandoHinn Thanks. I ready through that post. I believe it still only toggle the class on one particular node, and doesn't take into account the other elements in a group.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably go with events here.

You bind click, and if element without class is clicked you emit event in root scope to off all other elements and start listeinng to that event (so if other elem will be selected this will deselect itself).

```
app.directive('toggleFamily', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      function listen() {
        var bind = scope.$on('removeToggle', function(event) {
          elem.removeClass('toggled');
          bind();
        });
      }

      elem.bind('click', function() {
        if (elem.hasClass('toggled')) {
          elem.removeClass('toggled');
        } else {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('removeToggle');
          elem.addClass('toggled');
          listen();
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4sU9xayMOFa3reQNESGP?p=preview

Note. Usually you want to have model for everything in view. But if you want 'all elements everywhere' what you can store for selected element? id? no...
But if type of this elements is fixed, like you have:
`<div>{{person.name}}</div>` then you can store person.id and use ng-class.
This will force you to have some model on 'top-level' thow.