# Toggle Class Using Angular Directive

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to toggle a class using the code below (thanks to [Zombi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2867315/zombi) for the [directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418956/4180534) he made)

I cannot figure out how to change a class of an element "B" by clicking element "A". Could you please suggest anything?

Angular

```
module.directive('toggleClass', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
            element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
        });
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<li> <- Clicked Element
    <span toggle-class="open"></span> <-Toggled Class
</li>
```

Comment: it worked using the ng-class but I would like to stick to the directive since I will be using it everywhere in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, change your code like this:

```
module.directive('toggleClass', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.parent().bind('click', function() {
              element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
          });
      }
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/feydv6pL/8/)

Comment: Indeed :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Other thing is, what if I don't want the child element to be toggled? :) Asking just for future use...

Comment: Only change target from element.parent() to element

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to comment, yes I figured out :) Many thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass,"ng-class usage") directive of angularjs.There is lot more you can do with that

Comment: Thanks for the hint :)