# not able to covert jquery code into angularjs, need to toggle class using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to convert below piece of jquery code into angularjs.. Please help.

```
$('.favorite').click(function() 
{
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs toggle ng-class ng-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071984/angularjs-toggle-ng-class-ng-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<span ng-click="toggle()" ng-class="{active: isShown}">look at my class (working)</span><br>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.toggle = function () {
      $scope.isShown = !$scope.isShown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant try this:

```js
<button class="favorite" ng-click="state = !state" ng-class="{'active' : state}">Some text...</button>
```