# Adding Classes to Elements using ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list of `<p>` tags in my Angularjs appication that I would like to set an `active` class on when any of them are selected using the `ng-click` directive

```
<p ng-click="setActive()">Paragraph 1</p>
<p ng-click="setActive()">Paragraph 2</p>
<p ng-click="setActive()">Paragraph 3</p>
```

I've read one of the best ways to toggle an active class is to push each applicable object into an array and set the class by the array index; is their a simpler way to do this using html elements?

Note* these paragraphs will be rendered dynamically to the DOM as a result of an AJAX request

Comment: This code seems incomplete to understand your context.. Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As @Rayon stated we need to know the context in order to assist. e.g. are these paragraphs being generated in a ngRepeat??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs toggle ng-class ng-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071984/angularjs-toggle-ng-class-ng-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngClass` directive for this

```
  $scope.setActive = function(currentEl){
    $scope.currentEl = currentEl;
  };
<p ng-class="{ 'active' : currentEl == 'p1' }" ng-click="setActive('p1')">Paragraph 1</p>
<p ng-class="{ 'active' : currentEl == 'p2' }" ng-click="setActive('p2')">Paragraph 2</p>
<p ng-class="{ 'active' : currentEl == 'p3' }" ng-click="setActive('p3')">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Comment: Pleasure is mine :)