# Store and recall class using ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs

I have implemented an `ng-click` to toggle `<div>` tags between two **css** classes. An **'on' and 'off'** in this example.

The **'off'** class is used by default.

I feel that I should be using a boolean to track whether it has been clicked (true / false), but not sure how or where to implement that. Or is there a shorter way?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("clickToggle", function($scope) {

  $scope.class = "off";

  $scope.changeClass = function() {
    if ($scope.class === "off")
      $scope.class = "on";
    else
      $scope.class = "off"
  };

});
```

```css
.off {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 200px !important;
  font: 30px 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.on {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 200px !important;
  font: 30px 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.circle:hover {
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #9fa8da;
  color: #f7f3eb;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clickToggle">

  <div class="circle" ng-class="class" ng-click="changeClass()">1</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071984/angularjs-toggle-ng-class-ng-click or https://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/xtbzc

Answer (score 0):

If the **`.off`** class used by default then you can apply the default style to `.circle`.
Thereafter you just can switch on and off the `.on` class by clicks

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("clickToggle",['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.changeClass = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  };
}]);
```

```css
.circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  border-radius: 200px !important;
  font: 30px 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px, 10px, 10px, 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.on {
  background-color: blue;
}

.circle:hover {
  background: #9fa8da;
  color: #f7f3eb;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clickToggle">

  <div class="circle" ng-class="{'on': isActive}" ng-click="changeClass()">1</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a cleaner way of doing it. How would I store the fact that it has been 'clicked'? Initially im thinking this would just be a bool, than would change to 'true' when clicked - where should I declare this variable?